# Error while running studio.exe in installing Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I got an error while installing Android Studio and this is the error message:

```
Internal error. Please report to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find installation home path. Please make sure bin/idea.properties is present in the installation directory.
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.PathManager.getHomePath(PathManager.java:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.PathManager.loadProperties(PathManager.java:315)
    at com.intellij.ide.BootstrapClassLoaderUtil.initClassLoader(BootstrapClassLoaderUtil.java:58)
    at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:33)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:84)

2014-11-15 15:42:10 [Patch] Original patch does not exist: C:\Users\DANIEL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jetbrains.patch.jar.androidstudio
```

Comment: I have the same issue with android-studio-ide-135.1538390-windows

Answer (score 2):

In the beginning I pointed out there is something wrong with `bin/idea.properties` file. Maybe method `com.intellij.openapi.application.PathManager.getHomePath` could not find the `IDEA_HOME` path in my Windows environment variable. After some analysis I narrowed the error cause to the folder naming. I installed the Intellij IDE to custom folder: `C:\!DATA_STORAGE!\PROGRAM_FILES\Intellij`.
I tried to rename the folder with special character (exclamation). The results was:

```
C:\!DATA_STORAGE!\PROGRAM_FILES\Intellij - error
C:\DATA_STORAGE\PROGRAM_FILES\Intellij - OK (IntelliJ started)
C:\!DATA_STORAGE\PROGRAM_FILES\Intellij - OK
C:\DATA_STORAGE!\PROGRAM_FILES\Intellij - error
```

Finally I found the logic: whatever comes after the ! mark is inside the JAR file.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html

The behaviour has been raised as bug in Java 1.3, 1.4, 5.0.
http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4523159
There has been made a little change but overall the problem remains. The best existing solution is the workaround: don't use exclamation mark at the end of folder name or file name.